# 404 errors for existing files

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, url-rewriting

- Apache web server is insisting that the page we are trying to access
  is missing, but we know it isn't so.
- To make it more confusing, only  directory names are at issue. It is
  not a permissions problem on the files. because i dnt get an error
  404 when i try to access to index page .. i have a php files under a
  php directory exp (/php/ws_adresse.php) and a js page who's
  communicate with this ws , i just wanna add that i used to work with
  no errors , this problem has appears only when i changed server
  configuration.i tried to look at the log error but nothing is showin
  there .
- I am unsure as to how to proceed. Is there a way to make Apache
  reveal where on the filesystem it is looking for the file? Some way
  to test whether or not Apache would allow access to a specific
  directory based on its config, or a way to trace so that it explains
  why it thinks the file is 404? Inquiring minds want to know. Thank
  you

Comment: Either .htaccess or the host configuration can contain instructions to define specific behaviour (f.e. you can deny the access to physical files via configuration).

Comment: thank you .. are you familiar with apache.conf ? because i dnt have a .htaccess file . but the only think i did is that i enabled the mode rewrite .. when i tried to type the (http/www.exp.com/php/ws_adresse.php) the file does existe .. but it dosen't communicate with the js page... ( i didn't change anything on the code) it keep tells me that there's a 404 error file /php/ws_adresse.php (Not Found).. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the "autoindex" feature of Apache server, you could get some hints of which directories and files are accessible. You can do it by typing:

```
sudo a2enmod autoindex
```

This will enable directory listing in the server, so remember to disable it again when you are finished testing.

Comment: this module is already enable ? does error comes from that ? .. do you want me to put the apache.conf file above